# CSS include path messed up with vhost

Tags: php, html, web, slim

I am currently using SLIM as a PHP framework. I have a slight problem with paths (below is my file hierarchy).

I'd like to be able to have a clean url that presents itself like this: "https://cppoi/home", but by doing this my html includes no longer work as they are supposed to. It's as if they can't see outside their "bubble" or the vhost bubble, which points to "application/". If I however set it to point to the entire project folder, which includes the assets folder in which my stylesheets are located, my includes work again but my url becomes "https://cppoi/application/home" which is uglier.

There is probably a very easy solution to this, thanks for your time.

[image: Test]

Answer (score 1):

There is no super easy solution, your app setup doesn't necessarily follow best practices. You would usually setup a `public` folder that contains only your front controller `index.php` and any public assets. (+ stuff like `.htaccess`. This `public` folder is then exposed via webserver, nothing else. That way your code is not accessible from the web, but your main entry point (front controller) and your assets are.